# Не корректно работает range на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем большой привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть самописные range'ы. На десктопе они вроде работают, а вот на мобиле не совсем.

Вот разметка:

```js
if (document.querySelector('.price__slider') !== null) {
  // Инициализация трэка и бегунков
  var rangeRail = document.querySelector('.price__range_rail'),
    rangeTrack = document.querySelector('.price__range_track'),
    rangeHandleLeft = document.querySelector('.price__range_handle-1'),
    rangeHandleRight = document.querySelector('.price__range_handle-2');
  // Инициализация инпутов
  var inputMin = document.querySelector('.price__input_min'),
    inputMax = document.querySelector('.price__input_max'),
    valueMax = inputMax.getAttribute('aria-valuemax');
  // Стартовые положение для бегунков и их значений
  rangeHandleLeft.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + ((inputMin.value / valueMax * 100)) + '%;');
  rangeHandleRight.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + ((inputMax.value / valueMax * 100)) + '%;');

  rangeHandleLeft.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', inputMin.value);
  rangeHandleRight.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', inputMax.value);
  // Функция активации бегунков
  const activeButton = (el, handle, input, secondInput) => {
    // Прослушка нажатия на бегунок
    el.onmousedown = function(el) {
      // Переменная в которой лежит нажатая кнопка
      let button = el.currentTarget;
      // Переменная в которой лежит длинна всего пути трека
      let rail = Math.floor(rangeRail.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      // Прослушка движения мыши по экрану
      document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        // Распололжение клика
        e = (e.pageX - Math.floor(rangeRail.getBoundingClientRect().x));
        // Движение бегунка в %
        button.style.left = e / (rail / 100) + '%';
        // Запись значения в value
        Math.floor(button.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", e / (rail / 100)));
        // Проверка, чтобы бегунок не убегал за пределы трека
        if (e > rail) {
          button.style.left = '100%';
          Math.floor(button.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", 100));
        } else if (e <= 0) {
          button.style.left = '0%';
          Math.floor(button.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", 0));
        }
        // Проверка значения бегунка после движения
        let value = handle.getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
        // Запись значения в input
        input.setAttribute('value', Math.floor((inputMax.getAttribute("aria-valuemax") / 100) * value));

        if (secondInput == inputMax) {
          if (value > (secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) - 8) {
            button.style.left = ((secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) - 8) + '%';
            input.setAttribute('value', secondInput.value);
          }
        } else if (secondInput == inputMin) {
          if (value < (secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) + 8) {
            button.style.left = ((secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) + 8) + '%';
            input.setAttribute('value', secondInput.value);
          }
        }
      }
      // Отключения прослушки движения мыши, после завершения нажатия
      document.onmouseup = function() {
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }

    el.addEventListener('touchstart', function(el) {
      // Переменная в которой лежит нажатая кнопка
      let button = el.currentTarget;
      // Переменная в которой лежит длинна всего пути трека
      let rail = Math.floor(rangeRail.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      // Прослушка движения мыши по экрану
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        // Распололжение клика
        e = (e.changedTouches[0].clientX - rangeRail.getBoundingClientRect().x);
        // Движение бегунка в %
        button.style.left = e / (rail / 100) + '%';
        // Запись значения в value
        Math.floor(button.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", e / (rail / 100)));
        // Проверка, чтобы бегунок не убегал за пределы трека
        if (e > rail) {
          button.style.left = '100%';
          Math.floor(button.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", 100));
        } else if (e <= 0) {
          button.style.left = '0%';
          Math.floor(button.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", 0));
        }
        // Проверка значения бегунка после движения
        let value = handle.getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
        // Запись значения в input
        input.setAttribute('value', Math.floor((inputMax.getAttribute("aria-valuemax") / 100) * value));

        // if(secondInput == inputMax) {
        //     if(value > (secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) - 8) {  
        //         button.style.left = ((secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) - 8) + '%';
        //         input.setAttribute('value', secondInput.value);
        //     } 
        // } else if(secondInput == inputMin) {
        //     if(value < (secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) + 8) {
        //         button.style.left = ((secondInput.value / valueMax * 100) + 8) + '%';
        //         input.setAttribute('value', secondInput.value);
        //     }
        // }
        // Отключения прослушки движения мыши, после завершения нажатия

      })
      document.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
        console.log(el);
      })
    })
  }
  // Инициализация функций нажатия бегунков
  activeButton(rangeHandleLeft, rangeHandleLeft, inputMin, inputMax);
  activeButton(rangeHandleRight, rangeHandleRight, inputMax, inputMin);
}
```

```css
.filters .price__slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.filters .price__inputs {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.filters .price__inputs .line {
  display: block;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  height: 1px;
  width: 15px;
}

.filters .price__inputs input {
  width: 162px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-3);
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.filters .price__inputs input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.filters .price__inputs input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.filters .price__range {
  position: relative;
}

.filters .price__range_rail {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #828282;
}

.filters .price__range_handle-1,
.filters .price__range_handle-2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 10px solid #FFA11B;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -14px;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <div class="price__slider">
    <div class="price__inputs">
      <input class="price__input_min" aria-valuemin="0" type="number" value="1599">
      <span class="line"></span>
      <input class="price__input_max" aria-valuemax="45999" type="number" value="30999">
    </div>
    <div class="price__range">
      <div class="price__range_rail"></div>
      <div class="price__range_track"></div>
      <div class="price__range_handle-1" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow=""></div>
      <div class="price__range_handle-2" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос. В мобильной версии, когда дергаешь первый ползунок все норм, но как только переходишь ко второую первый сбрасывается и исчезает, ерзает только один и заполняет оба инпута одинаковыми значениями. При этом в десктопе все работает как надо.

Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, разобрался )

```js
 // Отключения прослушки движения мыши, после завершения нажатия
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', motionRange)
            document.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
                document.removeEventListener('touchmove', motionRange, false);
            })
```